# Check if PostgreSQL/C ArrayType is Zero-Based or One-Based

Tags: postgresql, function, aggregate-functions

I'm writing a PostgreSQL function in C and I'm using `deconstruct_array()` to get an ArrayType (let's call it `arr`) to a Datum array. Is there a way for me to easily check if `arr` is zero- or one-based (i.e. indices start at zero or one)?

Comment: In C all arrays start at 0.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Let me clarify what I mean: C arrays start at 0 but PostgreSQL arrays by default start at 1. In my case, I specify the PostgreSQL array to start at either 0 or 1 when I use `construct_md_array()` and when I use `deconstruct_array()` I need to check if the PostgreSQL array is one- or zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Solved -- used array_lower() to determine the lower bound and whether it is 0 or 1.